# step function problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$g(t)$

$= 0 $     for     $0\leq t <5$

$= (t-5)/5$  for $5\leq t < 10$

$= 1 $ for $t\geq 10$

my answer is $g(t) = 0 + u_{5}(t) (t-5)/5 + u_{10}(t) (t+10)/5$

but from the book answer is $g(t) = [u_{5}(t)(t-5)- u_{10}(t)(t-10) ]/5$

I don't understand... why

isn't $(t-5)/5$ less than $1$ ?

Comment: what if $t=20$?

Comment: What are $u_5$ and $u_{10} $.

Comment: it called unit step fucntion of Heaviside function. This function will be denoted by $u_c$ and is defined by $u_c(t) = 0 t<c$    and    $u_c(t) = 1 t\geq c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(t-5)\over5$ is only less than $1$ over the range $5<t<10$. For $10<t$, it is greater than $1$, so your next term now has to subtract an amount that gets it back to $1$. This is how you get $g(t) = [u_{5}(t)(t-5)- u_{10}(t)(t-10) ]/5$.

If you go into the range $10<t$, this becomes $${[(t-5)-(t-10)]\over5}={5\over5}=1$$

If we look at the simplification of $g(t) = 0 + u_{5}(t) (t-5)/5 + u_{10}(t) (t+10)/5$ over the range $10<t$, we obtain $${[(t-5)+(t+10)]\over 5}={2t+5\over5}=\frac{2}{5}t +1$$ which won't give the desired result.

Comment: 1- (t-5)/5  should be.. (-t+10)/5 but I kept getting (t+10)/5. miss - sign : /